# Find all possible event_id that were attend by tag_id 5 and 21

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

From this above table I will need the **event_ids** that **tag_id** 21 and 5 involved
in a single query. I want those event_ids that only 21 and 5 both visited

Comment: That is a really easy query.  What have you tried?

Comment: if i give IN (21,5)
That will also display those event_ids that are either 21 or 5 visited.
But I want those event_ids that only 21 and 5 both visited.

Thanks for quick reply guys

Comment: Can you give your expected output from above data?

Comment: This is a form of Relational Division.

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid thats seems worked...
But i didn't understand having count(distinct tag_id) = 2
Thanks...

Comment: @DevKamal having part will guarantee the existence of both tags in same event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need events that must have both of these tags then you can do so

```
select * from 
table
where tag_id IN (21,5)
group by event_id
having count(distinct tag_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE tag_id=21 OR tag_id=5;
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE tag_id IN (21,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Mysql `IN` for multiple numbers, like so:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE tag_id IN (21,5);`